# Forbidden (403) CSRF verification failed. Request aborted. with Gunicorn

Tags: django, gunicorn, http-status-code-403, csrf-token

I've created a form that includes the `{% csrf_token %}` but every time I submit the form it refuses it due to my domain not coming from a trusted origin.

I set `CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGIN = "https://proj.com"` and I even tried using `@csrf_exempt` to see if that would get rid of the problem but it still didn't work, the form still isn't submitting.

I am using gunicorn with my django project and PostgreSQL for my database.